Convert var to int with ClosedXml in C#
I want to convert my var in a cell to an int, I know it is an int because I know that this column in my .xlsx file is full of int, but Convert.ToInt32() makes an error;
I did:
var km = feuille.Cell("C" + num.Substring(1, 1)); //supposed to be C1,C2 or C with any number
return Convert.ToInt32(km);

But I get
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'ClosedXML.Excel.XLCell' to type 'System.IConvertible'.
at System.Convert.ToInt32(Object value)

Well, it sounds like the Cell method is returning ClosedXML.Excel.XLCell. Have you looked at what methods/properties that type provides? (Note that the title isn't really helpful - the type of km isn't var, it's ClosedXML.Excel.XLCell.)

feuille.Cell("C" + num.Substring(1, 1)) gets you the cell, not its value. So do this instead:
var cell = feuille.Cell("C" + num.Substring(1, 1));
var km = Convert.ToInt32(cell.Value);

As an asside: var is not really a type, it's just a syntax-shortcut which resolves to a compiletime-type. In your case var resolves to ClosedXML.Excel.XLCell. You can determine the actual type when you hover the variable in Visual Studio with your mouse.

var km = feuille.Cell("C" + num.Substring(1, 1)); gives a XLCell object and its
not convertable to int.
You need to get the value from XLCell which will be a string type and then try to convert the value into int.
Covert.ToInt32(km.Value) will convert the value into int.
It is better to use tryParse instead of Convert.ToInt32.
